# SQL - How to insert unique id in XML tag

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I get fixed XML from external system and I need in T-SQL to attach some unique ID in `<document>` tag and insert all data into 2 tables.

This is XML that I get:

```
<root>
    <document number="1234">
        <data1>
            <item1 d="100"/> 
            <item1 d="200"/> 
        </data1>
        <data2>
            <item2 d="111"/> 
            <item2 d="222"/> 
        </data2>
    </document> 
    <document number="1234">
        <data1>
            <item1 d="300"/> 
            <item1 d="400"/> 
        </data1>
    </document> 
    <document number="1234">
        <data1>
            <item1 d="500"/> 
        </data1>
        <data2>
            <item2 d="555"/> 
        </data2>
    </document> 
</root>
```

I need to insert above XML into 2 tables `tData1` and `tData2` with unique docid at the `<document>` level.

Table `tData1` should look like this:

```
docid    number     d
---------------------
    1      1234   100
    1      1234   200
    2      1234   300
    2      1234   400
    3      1234   500
```

Table `tData2` should look like this:

```
docid    number    d
---------------------
    1      1234   111
    1      1234   222
    3      1234   555
```

How I can insert `docid` field while converting above XML into these tables?

Comment: OK, that's a requirement. And what is the question or problem?

Comment: How can I insert docid while I converting XML to tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nodes` in a `CROSS APPLY`, like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML='<root>
    <document number="1234">
        <data1>
            <item1 d="100"/> 
            <item1 d="200"/> 
        </data1>
        <data2>
            <item2 d="111"/> 
            <item2 d="222"/> 
        </data2>
    </document> 
    <document number="1234">
        <data1>
            <item1 d="300"/> 
            <item1 d="400"/> 
        </data1>
    </document> 
    <document number="1234">
        <data1>
            <item1 d="500"/> 
        </data1>
        <data2>
            <item2 d="555"/> 
        </data2>
    </document> 
</root>'


SELECT Q1.docid, Q1.number, Q2.d
FROM (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.N1) AS docid,
            N1.value('@number','varchar(10)') AS number,
            N1.query('.') AS X
    FROM @x.nodes('root/document') T1(N1)
) Q1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT N2.value('@d','varchar(10)') AS d
    FROM Q1.x.nodes('document/data1/item1') T2(N2)
) Q2

SELECT Q1.docid, Q1.number, Q2.d
FROM (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.N1) AS docid,
            N1.value('@number','varchar(10)') AS number,
            N1.query('.') AS X
    FROM @x.nodes('root/document') T1(N1)
) Q1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT N2.value('@d','varchar(10)') AS d
    FROM Q1.x.nodes('document/data2/item2') T2(N2)
) Q2
```

To generate `docid` I have used ROW_NUMBER over the node column, as explained in http://dataeducation.com/uniquely-identifying-xml-nodes-with-dense_rank/.